# Let $R$ be a total order. Is $R^{-1}$ a total order?

Tags: order-theory

Let us assume that $R$ is a total order on a set $A$. Is its inverse, $R^{-1}$, also a total order on the set $A$?

Clearly $R$ is also a partial order and thus $R^{-1}$ is a partial order, so all that remains to prove (from the set of total order axioms)  is that all the elements of $A$ are related to each other by $R^{-1}$, i.e.

\begin{align}
\forall x \in A \forall y \in A (xR^{-1}y \lor yR^{-1}x).
\end{align}

I attempt to prove this by contradiction. Let $R$ be a total order on $A$ and $R^{-1}$ not a total order. This is equivalent to stating that

\begin{align}
[\forall x \in A \forall y \in A (xRy \lor yRx)] \land \lnot[\forall x \in A \forall y \in A (xR^{-1}y \lor yR^{-1}x)].
\end{align}
The right term of the conjunction is equivalent to $\exists x \in A \exists y \in A ((x,y) \notin R^{-1} \land (y,x) \notin R^{-1})$.
By using existential instantiation on this statement, I claim that
$x_o$ and $y_o$ are such examples such that
\begin{align}
  (x_o,y_o) \notin R^{-1} \land (y_o,x_o) \notin R^{-1}.
\end{align}
By using the rule of simplification, the definition of the inverse relation and the finally, the rule of conjunction, on the previous statement, I arrive at
\begin{align}
(y_o,x_o)\notin R \land (x_o,y_o)  \notin R.
\end{align}

However, when I universally instantiate $\forall x \in A \forall y \in A (xRy \lor yRx)$ (one of the initial assumptions) for $x_o$ and $y_o$, I get
\begin{align}
x_oRy_o \lor y_oRx_o
\end{align}
Which contradicts the previous statement, i.e. $(y_o,x_o)\notin R \land (x_o,y_o)  \notin R$. Thus $R^{-1}$ needs to be a total ordering on $A$.

I can't shake the feeling that I made a mistake...Is all of this correct?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Contradiction is not helpful here. A direct proof is much more straightforward: if $R$ is total then, for any $x, y$, either $x R y$ or $y R x$, so as $aRb$ is equivalent to $bR^{-1}a$ for any $a, b$, we must have that either $y R^{-1}x$ or $x R^{-1}y$. So $R^{-1}$ is total.

Comment: I originally did use proof by cases, but I thought that I made a universal generalization when I already partitioned my claims and I thought that was incorrect.
Thank you for the neat solution!